# Java error when running ionic build android

Tags: javascript, java, android, cordova, ionic-framework

After installing ionic and android sdk one windows, I tried to build a sample app running the command `ionic build android`.
It so happens that after running this command, and after some seconds the following message appears:

> Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
>              (to execute a class)    or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
>              (to execute a jar file) where options include:
>       -d32          use a 32-bit data model if available
>       -d64          use a 64-bit data model if available
>       -server       to select the "server" VM
>                     The default VM is server.
>
> ```
> -cp <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
> -classpath <class search path of directories and zip/jar files>
>               A ; separated list of directories, JAR archives,
>               and ZIP archives to search for class files.
> -D<name>=<value>
>               set a system property
> -verbose:[class|gc|jni]
>               enable verbose output
> -version      print product version and exit
> -version:<value>
>               Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
>               in a future release.
>               require the specified version to run
> -showversion  print product version and continue
> -jre-restrict-search | -no-jre-restrict-search
>               Warning: this feature is deprecated and will be removed
>               in a future release.
>               include/exclude user private JREs in the version search
> -? -help      print this help message
> -X            print help on non-standard options
> -ea[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
> -enableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
>               enable assertions with specified granularity
> -da[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
> -disableassertions[:<packagename>...|:<classname>]
>               disable assertions with specified granularity
> -esa | -enablesystemassertions
>               enable system assertions
> -dsa | -disablesystemassertions
>               disable system assertions
> -agentlib:<libname>[=<options>]
>               load native agent library <libname>, e.g. -agentlib:hprof
>               see also, -agentlib:jdwp=help and -agentlib:hprof=help
> -agentpath:<pathname>[=<options>]
>               load native agent library by full pathname
> -javaagent:<jarpath>[=<options>]
>               load Java programming language agent, see java.lang.instrument
>
> -splash:<imagepath>
>               show splash screen with specified image See http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index.html
> ```
>
> for more details.
>
> Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1

For this error I tried to reinstall java JDK7 and also installed JAVA8, and also I switched node version (tried node 8 and 6) , but nothing has worked. Because this error is so generic, I am having difficulties knowing what should I look for.

I'm also running windows 7.

Can anyone help me with this?